# Mapping array value in API response for conditional check

Tags: reactjs, superagent, array.prototype.map

I have an api which loads a response with an array value I need to map, in order to both check if available, and if so, use the `id` value of the `offers` to display later. I'm currently able to simply get the `available` option, but need to be able to map down to the `offers` and grab the id value within the `FETCH OFFER DETAILS` fetchContent.

**API RESPONSE**

```
{
  "available": true,
  "offers": [
    {
      "days_free": 30,
      "id": 1,
    }
  ]
}
```

**React Component**

```
class CancelOffer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: []
    }
    this.processData = this.processData.bind(this)
    this.cancelAccount = this.cancelAccount.bind(this)
    this.acceptPromo = this.acceptPromo.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchContent(this.processData)
  }

  /**
   * Fetch offer details
   */

  fetchContent (cb) {
    superagent
      .get('/api/user/offers')
      .then(function(res) {
        /**
        * If res.body.available === true, get offers.id and use in 
          acceptPromo.
        * Else if not true, redirect to 
         .then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))
        */
        if(res.body.available){
          const offerCode = res.body.offers[0].id
          alert(offerCode)
        } else {
          this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE)
        }
      })
  }

  /**
   * Set state after user have been fetched
   * @param data
   */
  processData (data) {
    this.setState({
      user: data.body.offers
    })
  }

  /**
  * Send accept promo offer code
  */
  acceptPromo (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    superagent
      .post('/api/user/offers')
      .send({
        offerId: offerCode <==THIS NEEDS TO COME FROM THE API RESPONSE 
      })
      .then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))
  }

  render () {
    const content = this.props.config.contentStrings
    const daysFree = this.state.user.map((daysFree, i) => {
      return (
        <span>{daysFree.days_free}</span>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div className='offer'>
        <h2 className='offer-heading md'>Heading</h2>
        <p className='offer-subpara'>sub paragraph {daysFree}</p>
        <div className='footer-links'>
          <a onClick={this.acceptPromo} className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>accept promo</a>
          <a onClick={this.cancelAccount} className='cancel-link'>cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default CancelOffer
```

Comment: if the response is set into `state.user`, you can access the ID with `this.state.user.offers[0].id` (assuming that you always want the first ID of offers array)

Comment: Do you mean by setting it in the `.then(function(res) { if(res.body){}})`?

Comment: yes, you can save the fetched data inside fetch success callback into some variable (avoid set into the state if you don't need it), like `this.fetchedData = res.body;` and then you can access it with `this.fetchedData.user.offers[0].id` later on

Comment: I used your suggestion, slightly modified to a `const`. However, I'm getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: offerCode is not defined` when triggering `acceptPromo`. I've updated my code above.

Comment: @Dario - I think it might be a scope issue, but I should be able to pass the const `offerCode` to the `acceptOffer` function, right?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - ANSWER:

I needed to set the promo code in state

```
fetchContent (cb) {
superagent
  .get('/api/user/offers')
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.body.available){
      this.setState({
        offerId: res.body.offers[0].id
      })
    } else {
      this.props.setStep(OFFER)
    }
  })
 }
```

and pass it to the accept promo

```
acceptPromo (e) {
e.preventDefault()
const { offerId } = this.state
superagent
  .post('/api/user/offers')
  .send({offerId})
  .then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))
}
```